# Borel set of $\mathbb R^n$ with $n > 1$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, probability-theory

According to various sources, the Borel set over $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be defined in several equivalent ways:

For instance, it can be defined as the smallest sigma-algebra containing every open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or the smallest sigma-algebra containing the sets  $(a_1, b_1) \times ... \times (a_n, b_n)$ for $a_1, ..., a_n, b_1, ..., b_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

I did not manage to find any demonstration for this equivalence, and to me it seems to be false so I would like to know where is the flaw in my reasoning.

I assumed $n = 2$ and thanks to the  properties of a sigma algebra, I restated the problem with closed sets.

If the above definitions are equivalent then
the smallest sigma-algebra containing every closed set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ must be the same as as the one generated by the rectangles $[a_1, b_1] \times [a_2, b_2]$.
While it is obvious that the second sigma algebra is  included in the first, I think there are closed sets that can't be expressed as a countable union of rectangles.

For example if you take a closed triangle $A(0,0)$ $B(1, 0)$ $C(1, 1)$ and consider the side $[AC]$, it is neither horizontal nor vertical therefore every point of $[AC]$ must be a corner of a rectangle, which means at least as much rectangles are needed to fill the triangle as there are points in $[AC]$ which is not a countable set AFAIK.

I think my idea can be easily generalized for any $n \geq 2$.

I believe I either made a mistake somewhere in my proof or I did not understand the definition for the borel set over $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In any case I'd be happy to know where the flaw is.

Thank you.

Comment: So here is my mistake : I assumed wrongly that the sigma algebra generated by the closed rectangles must be made only from countable unions of those generating rectangles because a sigma algebra is closed under countable union. But here we have the proof that it is false. The open rectangles are infinite countable unions of the closed rectangles but new sets of different kind can be formed from countable unions of open rectangles which are impossible to form only from the initial family.

Answer (score 4):

We show directly that the two definitions are equivalent: We need only to show that all open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ can be written as a countable union of open rectangles.

Let $V \in \mathbb R^n$ be open. Let $C$ be its complement. Let $Q$ be a countable dense subset in $V$. For each $p \in Q$, define

$$r_p = \sup \{r >0 : (p_1-r, p_1+r) \times \cdots \times (p_n-r,p_n+r) \subset V\}$$

Note that $r_p >0$. Also the square

$$S_p(r_p) = (p_1-r_p, p_1+r_p) \times \cdots \times (p_n-r_p,p_n+r_p)$$

is contained in $V$

Claim: $V = \bigcup _{p\in Q} S_p(r_p)$.

To see this, let $v\in V$. Then similarly define $r_v$. Then $S_v(r_v)$ is contained in $V$. As $Q$ is dense in $V$, there is $p\in Q$ so that $|v_i-p_i|< r_v/3$ for all $i$. Then the square $S_p(r_v/2)$ is contained in $S_v(r_v)$. Thus $r_p >r_v$. Also $v \in S_p(r_v)$. Thus $v \in S_p(r_p)$.

Comment: How  do you know that every $x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \Delta ABC$ is contained in a $R_p$ for some $p \in Q$ ? Even knowing that rationals are dense in the reals I don't see why, maybe the radius of the balls is never big enough

Comment: @Guest: Indeed I am just using the fact that $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \triangle ABC$ is open. Then for all $p$ in this set (In particular if $p \in Q$), there is an open ball in this open set containing $p$. In this open ball then I find an open rectangle.

Comment: Yes i understand what you are telling but how do you know that the non rational points $ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \Delta ABC$ can be put in one of those open rectangle ? with density we can find a sequence points $(p_n) \in Q^{\mathbb{N}}$ which converge to that $x$ but maybe the $R_{p_n}$ will always be too small to contain the $x$ , am i wrong?

Comment: Good spot. Actually you are correct. Let me edit the answer @Guest

Comment: @Guest : Please see the edit.

Comment: Yes that proof looks nice, thank you.

Comment: @Guest : It's just modified (to deal directly with squares)

Comment: So what is wrong with my proof that $\sigma(\{A closed \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\}) \neq \sigma(\{[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2, b_2] ; a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2 \in \mathbb{R}\})$ ? Because I think these sets are also the Borel set over $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Ok I found out my big problem was that I thought that every set $A$ of a sigma algebra generated by a family $F$ must be a countable union of members of that family but it is not true, it can actually be a countable union of countable unions for example. Ok now everything is clear thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Any open set $U\subset\mathbb R^2$ is a countable union of open rectangles $(a,b)\times(c,d)$.
Not every closed set $C\subset\mathbb R^2$ is a countable union of closed rectangles $[a,b]\times[c,d]$.

The same thing happens with open and closed balls, too.
In an open set you always have a little bit of room to find a rectangle around any point, but in a closed set this is not possible around boundary points.

Comment: I suppose the second sentence should say "closed rectangles"?

Comment: @Math1000, indeed. Corrected. Thanks!